# Terraform aws_ssm_parameter overwrite alternative

Tags: terraform

Since the 'overwrite' attribute is deprecated as of Terraform version 5 (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-5-upgrade#resourceaws_ssm_parameter),

I have a certain aws_ssm_parameter resource that has the attribute of 'overwrite' = true.
I am trying to find a workaround for this setting and Would love to hear any ideas.
Thank you

Comment: From what I understood, you just need to import the parameters into state after moving to version 5 of the provider. But your question is lacking details, so hard to tell.

Comment: Not sure what details you are missing. I have a aws_ssm_parameter resource with the attribue 'overwrite'=true and since its deprecated i need a workaroud to achieve the same behavior

Comment: Overwrite applies to overwriting parameters not created by terraform. So, the terraform documentation says that you have explicitly import existing parameters not managed by terraform. If your parameters are managed by terraform, then overwrite is not needed.

Comment: This issue he is referring to is when you create a parameter using Terraform and after that you try to update the value of parameter. If the overwrite attribute is not which is by default false, it won't let you overwrite the parameter value. If it is set and set to true, then it will overwrite the value but throw us a warning that this parameter is deprecated.